# Limitar el número de echos de un output PHP

Tags: php

Este [repositorio de Github](https://github.com/TuberBoy/DotMailsGenerator-PHP/blob/main/index.php) sirve para añadir un punto (.) a una dirección de Gmail y así registrarte en un sitio múltiples veces con direcciones aleatorias derivadas de la original.

El código funciona bien, si el correo es corto (ejemplo: hola123@gmail.com, genera unas cuentas direcciones, **el problema viene cuando el correo es MUY largo** (ejemplo: nombresyambosapellidos@gmail.com) pues el código genera MILES de correos aleatorios que alentan la página. (aprox 5,000)

La pregunta es si hay alguna forma de que dicho sistema se limite únicamente a unos 20 resultados sin importar que tan largo es el correo original?

Al ser nuevo este lenguaje, no encontré nada en el código ni nada en Stackoverflow para cambiar eso :(

Adjunto únicamente **el código PHP** de dicho repositorio:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $mail = explode('@', $_POST['email']);
    $email = $mail[0];
    $domain = '@'.$mail[1];
    $email = ltrim($email);
    $domain = ltrim($domain);
    $email = rtrim($email);
    $domain = rtrim($domain);
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $domain = stripslashes($domain);
    $email = htmlentities($email);
    $domain = htmlentities($domain);
    $res = addDOT($email);
    echo '<div class="box"><div class="title">Total: '.sizeof($res).'</div><textarea type="text">';
    foreach($res as $mcMails)
    {
        echo nl2br($mcMails.$domain).PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</textarea></div>';
}

function addDOT($str){ 
    if(strlen($str) > 1)
    {
        $ca = preg_split("//",$str); 
        array_shift($ca); 
        array_pop($ca); 
        $head = array_shift($ca); 
        $res = addDOT(join('',$ca)); 
        $result = array(); 
        foreach($res as $val)
        { 
          $result[] = $head . $val; 
          $result[] = $head . '.' .$val; 
        } 
        return $result; 
    } 
    return array($str); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Actualización

Mejor lo limitas dentro de la función addDOT para ahorrar recursos de este modo:

```
        foreach($res as $val)
        { 
            if (count($result) <= 18) {
                $result[] = $head . $val; 
                $result[] = $head . '.' .$val; 
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Pongo el 18 porque luego va a generar dos más, llegando a 20 en total.

### Respuesta anterior

**Nota**: Esta respuesta consume más recursos pues recibe la totalidad de casos de la función addDOT. Evitarla.

Tan solo debes añadirle un contador:

```
$contaje = 0;
foreach($res as $mcMails)
    {
        $contaje++;
        if($contaje <= 20) {
            echo nl2br($mcMails.$domain).PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo! Me funcionó perfectamente! Ya hasta estaba buscando como resolver lo del límite de memoria hahaha